# moduleResolution is node, but compile time is different from run time

Tags: typescript

I have a Node Express project, and my `moduleResolution` is set to `node`. tsc is able to resolve and compile the following without errors:

`app.ts` contains:

```
import { HttpError} from "myTypes";
```

`tsconfig.js` has:

```
"paths": {
        "*": [
            "node_modules/*",
            "src/types/*"
        ]
    }
```

The folder structure is:

```
/src---types
  |      |--myTypes.ts
  |
  |----app.ts
```

The `outDir` folder has the same `types` folder in the same hierarchy and the `myTypes.js` file is in there.

However, at run time I hit a `Cannot find module 'myTypes'` error. Why is this the case?

PS: I hope to use a non-relative module import. It works fine if I just use `import { HttpError} from "./types/myTypes";`. But I want to understand why the above is not working.

---

`myTypes.ts` contains:

```
export class HttpError {
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
  constructor(status?: number, msg?: string) {
    this.statusCode = status;
    this.message = msg;
 }
```

}

Comment: What exactly is myTypes and how is HttpError used?

Comment: myTypes contains just an exported class. I have added it in.

Comment: I see. So the import is real, not just a type. paths don't affect runtime. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039#issuecomment-232470330 . I'd suggest to stick to the same way you would do that in raw Node.